# Why is my altcoin node not syncing new blocks?

Tags: blockchain, altcoin

I setup a new node for my custom altcoin. I cloned and compiled altcoin in my ubuntu server machine. I have generated genesis block and added checkpoints for first two blocks..

I am able to connect to two nodes running in mac and unix, but new blocks are not downloaded and synced by the node. Why is this happening?

Here is my chainparams.cpp

```
class CMainParams : public CChainParams {
public:
    CMainParams() {
        strNetworkID = "main";
        consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval = 100000;
        consensus.BIP34Height = 710000;
        consensus.BIP34Hash = uint256S("e6024058338254100b68f794f3a5d14f9b9a7f0bfb68bf302d63c47c027b64ca");
        consensus.BIP65Height = 918684; // bab3041e8977e0dc3eeff63fe707b92bde1dd449d8efafb248c27c8264cc311a
        consensus.BIP66Height = 811879; // 7aceee012833fa8952f8835d8b1b3ae233cd6ab08fdb27a771d2bd7bdc491894
        consensus.powLimit = uint256S("00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"); 
        consensus.nPowTargetTimespan = 3.5 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3.5 days
        consensus.nPowTargetSpacing = 2.5 * 60;
        consensus.fPowAllowMinDifficultyBlocks = false;
        consensus.fPowNoRetargeting = false;
        consensus.nRuleChangeActivationThreshold = 6048; // 75% of 8064
        consensus.nMinerConfirmationWindow = 8064; // nPowTargetTimespan / nPowTargetSpacing * 4
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].bit = 28;
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nStartTime = 1199145601; // January 1, 2008
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nTimeout = 1230767999; // December 31, 2008

        // Deployment of BIP68, BIP112, and BIP113.
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].bit = 0;
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nStartTime = 1485561600; // January 28, 2017
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nTimeout = 1517356801; // January 31st, 2018

        // Deployment of SegWit (BIP141, BIP143, and BIP147)
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].bit = 1;
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nStartTime = 1485561600; // January 28, 2017
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nTimeout = 1517356801; // January 31st, 2018

        // The best chain should have at least this much work.
        consensus.nMinimumChainWork = uint256S("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300030");

        // By default assume that the signatures in ancestors of this block are valid.
        consensus.defaultAssumeValid = uint256S("0xa0e32c5522a08f54cbe2ad28b6a5168f424da9b68dea3fd18ae7742a87692a60"); //1353397

        /**
         * The message start string is designed to be unlikely to occur in normal data.
         * The characters are rarely used upper ASCII, not valid as UTF-8, and produce
         * a large 32-bit integer with any alignment.
         */
        pchMessageStart[0] = 0xfb;
        pchMessageStart[1] = 0xc0;
        pchMessageStart[2] = 0xb6;
        pchMessageStart[3] = 0xdb;
        nDefaultPort = 26201;
        nPruneAfterHeight = 100000;

        genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1518803474, 4251767 , 0x1e0ffff0, 1, 1000 * COIN);
        consensus.hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();



        //printf("Genesis hash:  %s\n", consensus.hashGenesisBlock.ToString().c_str());
        //printf("Merkel root:  %s\n", genesis.hashMerkleRoot.ToString().c_str());


        assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0xe6024058338254100b68f794f3a5d14f9b9a7f0bfb68bf302d63c47c027b64ca"));
        assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0x29b1458191d86739ff3ef0f179c0927a95cb89fa054e3e2a41dfe843ee0acc42"));

        // Note that of those with the service bits flag, most only support a subset of possible options
        //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.citizenshipcoin.org", true);
        //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.thrasher.io", true);
        //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.litecointools.com", true);
        //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.litecoinpool.org", true);
        //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.koin-project.com", false);

        base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,11);
        base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,5);
        base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS2] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,50);
        base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY] =     std::vector<unsigned char>(1,176);
        base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xB2, 0x1E};
        base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xAD, 0xE4};

        vFixedSeeds = std::vector<SeedSpec6>(pnSeed6_main, pnSeed6_main + ARRAYLEN(pnSeed6_main));

        fDefaultConsistencyChecks = false;
        fRequireStandard = true;
        fMineBlocksOnDemand = false;

        checkpointData = (CCheckpointData) {
            {
                { 0, uint256S("0xe6024058338254100b68f794f3a5d14f9b9a7f0bfb68bf302d63c47c027b64ca")},
                { 1, uint256S("0xb531f9d60406ca40b36e96233ab4243401696652bacba1dac0d67a0a93394216")},
                { 2, uint256S("0xa0e32c5522a08f54cbe2ad28b6a5168f424da9b68dea3fd18ae7742a87692a60")},
            /*  { 23420, uint256S("0xd80fdf9ca81afd0bd2b2a90ac3a9fe547da58f2530ec874e978fce0b5101b507")},
                { 50000, uint256S("0x69dc37eb029b68f075a5012dcc0419c127672adb4f3a32882b2b3e71d07a20a6")},
                { 80000, uint256S("0x4fcb7c02f676a300503f49c764a89955a8f920b46a8cbecb4867182ecdb2e90a")},
                {120000, uint256S("0xbd9d26924f05f6daa7f0155f32828ec89e8e29cee9e7121b026a7a3552ac6131")},
                {161500, uint256S("0xdbe89880474f4bb4f75c227c77ba1cdc024991123b28b8418dbbf7798471ff43")},
                {179620, uint256S("0x2ad9c65c990ac00426d18e446e0fd7be2ffa69e9a7dcb28358a50b2b78b9f709")},
                {240000, uint256S("0x7140d1c4b4c2157ca217ee7636f24c9c73db39c4590c4e6eab2e3ea1555088aa")},
                {383640, uint256S("0x2b6809f094a9215bafc65eb3f110a35127a34be94b7d0590a096c3f126c6f364")},
                {409004, uint256S("0x487518d663d9f1fa08611d9395ad74d982b667fbdc0e77e9cf39b4f1355908a3")},
                {456000, uint256S("0xbf34f71cc6366cd487930d06be22f897e34ca6a40501ac7d401be32456372004")},
                {638902, uint256S("0x15238656e8ec63d28de29a8c75fcf3a5819afc953dcd9cc45cecc53baec74f38")},
                {721000, uint256S("0x198a7b4de1df9478e2463bd99d75b714eab235a2e63e741641dc8a759a9840e5")}, */
            }
        };

        chainTxData = ChainTxData{
            // Data as of block 59c9b9d3fec105bdc716d84caa7579503d5b05b73618d0bf2d5fa639f780a011 (height 1353397).
            1516406833, // * UNIX timestamp of last known number of transactions
            19831879,  // * total number of transactions between genesis and that timestamp
                    //   (the tx=... number in the SetBestChain debug.log lines)
            0.06     // * estimated number of transactions per second after that timestamp
        };
    }
};
```

Here is by debug.log

```
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Citizenshipcoin version v0.15.1.0-75a93c0-dirty
2018-02-23 19:05:47 InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Assuming ancestors of block a0e32c5522a08f54cbe2ad28b6a5168f424da9b68dea3fd18ae7742a87692a60 have valid signatures.
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Setting nMinimumChainWork=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300030
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Using the 'standard' SHA256 implementation
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Using RdRand as an additional entropy source
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Default data directory /home/ubuntu/.citizenshipcoin
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Using data directory /home/ubuntu/.citizenshipcoin
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Using config file /home/ubuntu/.citizenshipcoin/citizenshipcoin.conf
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Using at most 125 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Using 0 threads for script verification
2018-02-23 19:05:47 HTTP: creating work queue of depth 16
2018-02-23 19:05:47 No rpcpassword set - using random cookie authentication
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Generated RPC authentication cookie /home/ubuntu/.citizenshipcoin/.cookie
2018-02-23 19:05:47 HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Cache configuration:
2018-02-23 19:05:47 * Using 2.0MiB for block index database
2018-02-23 19:05:47 * Using 8.0MiB for chain state database
2018-02-23 19:05:47 * Using 440.0MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 286.1MiB of unused mempool space)
2018-02-23 19:05:47 init message: Loading block index...
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Opening LevelDB in /home/ubuntu/.citizenshipcoin/blocks/index
2018-02-23 19:05:47 scheduler thread start
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Opened LevelDB successfully
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Using obfuscation key for /home/ubuntu/.citizenshipcoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2018-02-23 19:05:47 LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 0
2018-02-23 19:05:47 LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=1, size=279, heights=0...0, time=2018-02-16...2018-02-16)
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Checking all blk files are present...
2018-02-23 19:05:47 LoadBlockIndexDB: transaction index disabled
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Opening LevelDB in /home/ubuntu/.citizenshipcoin/chainstate
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Opened LevelDB successfully
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Using obfuscation key for /home/ubuntu/.citizenshipcoin/chainstate: 4d403349b0ea8d57
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Loaded best chain: hashBestChain=e6024058338254100b68f794f3a5d14f9b9a7f0bfb68bf302d63c47c027b64ca height=0 date=2018-02-16 17:51:14 progress=0.000000
2018-02-23 19:05:47 init message: Rewinding blocks...
2018-02-23 19:05:47 init message: Verifying blocks...
2018-02-23 19:05:47  block index              16ms
2018-02-23 19:05:47 No wallet support compiled in!
2018-02-23 19:05:47 mapBlockIndex.size() = 1
2018-02-23 19:05:47 nBestHeight = 0
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Bound to [::]:26201
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Bound to 0.0.0.0:26201
2018-02-23 19:05:47 init message: Loading P2P addresses...
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Loaded 0 addresses from peers.dat  0ms
2018-02-23 19:05:47 init message: Loading banlist...
2018-02-23 19:05:47 init message: Starting network threads...
2018-02-23 19:05:47 init message: Done loading
2018-02-23 19:05:47 opencon thread start
2018-02-23 19:05:47 addcon thread start
2018-02-23 19:05:47 msghand thread start
2018-02-23 19:05:47 dnsseed thread start
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Loading addresses from DNS seeds (could take a while)
2018-02-23 19:05:47 0 addresses found from DNS seeds
2018-02-23 19:05:47 dnsseed thread exit
2018-02-23 19:05:47 net thread start
2018-02-23 19:05:47 torcontrol thread start
2018-02-23 19:05:47 Imported mempool transactions from disk: 0 successes, 0 failed, 0 expired
2018-02-23 19:05:48 receive version message: /LitecoinCore:0.15.1/: version 70015, blocks=0, us=13.59.89.11:26201, peer=0
2018-02-23 19:06:37 receive version message: /LitecoinCore:0.15.1/: version 70015, blocks=2, us=13.59.89.11:26201, peer=1
2018-02-23 19:15:32 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 540 seconds ago)
2018-02-23 19:18:32 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 720 seconds ago)
```

I issue getpeerinfo command in my added node,

```
ipcoin-cli getpeerinfo
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "addr": "79.137.71.7:65242",
    "addrlocal": "13.59.189.11:26201",
    "addrbind": "172.31.6.242:26201",
    "services": "000000000000000d",
    "relaytxes": true,
    "lastsend": 1519413109,
    "lastrecv": 1519413109,
    "bytessent": 681,
    "bytesrecv": 650,
    "conntime": 1519412748,
    "timeoffset": -3,
    "pingtime": 0.116749,
    "minping": 0.116529,
    "version": 70015,
    "subver": "/LitecoinCore:0.15.1/",
    "inbound": true,
    "addnode": false,
    "startingheight": 0,
    "banscore": 0,
    "synced_headers": -1,
    "synced_blocks": -1,
    "inflight": [
    ],
    "whitelisted": false,
    "bytessent_per_msg": {
      "addr": 55,
      "feefilter": 32,
      "getheaders": 93,
      "ping": 128,
      "pong": 128,
      "sendcmpct": 66,
      "sendheaders": 24,
      "verack": 24,
      "version": 131
    },
    "bytesrecv_per_msg": {
      "feefilter": 32,
      "getaddr": 24,
      "getheaders": 93,
      "ping": 128,
      "pong": 128,
      "sendcmpct": 66,
      "sendheaders": 24,
      "verack": 24,
      "version": 131
    }
  }, 
  {
    "id": 1,
    "addr": "185.199.28.08:56583",
    "addrlocal": "13.59.89.11:26201",
    "addrbind": "172.31.6.242:26201",
    "services": "000000000000000d",
    "relaytxes": true,
    "lastsend": 1519413157,
    "lastrecv": 1519413157,
    "bytessent": 533,
    "bytesrecv": 737,
    "conntime": 1519412797,
    "timeoffset": 0,
    "pingtime": 0.140447,
    "minping": 0.139958,
    "version": 70015,
    "subver": "/LitecoinCore:0.15.1/",
    "inbound": true,
    "addnode": false,
    "startingheight": 2,
    "banscore": 0,
    "synced_headers": -1,
    "synced_blocks": -1,
    "inflight": [
    ],
    "whitelisted": false,
    "bytessent_per_msg": {
      "feefilter": 32,
      "ping": 128,
      "pong": 128,
      "sendcmpct": 66,
      "sendheaders": 24,
      "verack": 24,
      "version": 131
    },
    "bytesrecv_per_msg": {
      "addr": 55,
      "feefilter": 32,
      "getaddr": 24,
      "getheaders": 125,
      "ping": 128,
      "pong": 128,
      "sendcmpct": 66,
      "sendheaders": 24,
      "verack": 24,
      "version": 131
    }
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated:))

Comment: Thank you. It started to work, after i created more blocks. ))

Comment: how did u create new blocks exactly?

Comment: @r0otchixor using generate